# PHP include files from another directory that also include files

Tags: php, include, directory

I have includes in multiple files, i recently started a new directory and am unable to get some of my includes to work.

for example i have this include in my postpage.php which is located at example.com/c/postpage.php:

```
include '../includes/overall/header.php';
```

which works as it goes to the root directory and includes header.php 
but my problem is that header.php also includes files which are not being included.

the code in header.php is:

```
include 'includes/head.php';
```

which is not working

if i change header.php to:

```
include '../includes/head.php';
```

then it breaks the rest of my site, while working only for postpage.php

any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way, to prevent changes in CWD that might break relative paths is to include files using absolute paths.

An easy way to accomplish this is by using the `__DIR__` constant.

Example:

File structure:

```
serverRoot (/)
    |-usr
        |-local
            |-www
                |-index.php
                |-bootstrap.php
                |-includes
                    |-a.php
                    |-overall
                        |-b.php
                        |-c.php
```

let's say that:

- **index.php** includes **bootstrap.php** and **a.php**
- **a.php** includes **b.php**
- **bootstrap.php** includes **c.php**

index.php

```
$basedir = realpath(__DIR__);
include($basedir . '/bootstrap.php');
include($basedir . '/includes/a.php');
```

a.php

```
global $basedir;
include($basedir . '/includes/overall/b.php');
```

bootstrap.php

```
global $basedir;
include($basedir . '/includes/overall/c.php');
```

Comment: the $basedir will contain the same values in a.php and bootstrap.php even if its declared in a completely different file?

Comment: this is kindly like what I meant... just a better way of doing it. this should deffinantly fix it.

Comment: Yes, its just like any other variable declared in the global scope. You declare it in the point of entry of your script (usually the index.php file) and use it throughout your script

Comment: I really like this method.. I may start using this on my sites.

Comment: ya this worked, just added in the variable globally. thank you very much

Comment: glad to hear it. no prob mate

Answer (score 1):

I do this by creating a variable on the beginning of every page. The variable is simply the path to the top level directory.

example...

instead of

```
 include 'includes/head.php';
```

use:

```
 $pathToRoot = '../';
 include $pathToRoot.'includes/head.php';
```

but you will have to create this variable on the top of every page and change all include and require statements.

Comment: right but a majority of my pages dont want to send the include up a directory. i guess what im asking may not be possible

Answer (score 1):

You can check this part of the PHP documentation :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> Files are **included based on the file path given** or, if none is given,
>   the **include_path specified**. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will **finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory** and the current working directory before failing.

I suggest you either :

- To **include with absolute paths** (not recommended, quick and dirty)
- Change your **include_path** (`php.ini`) so you won't have any problems!
- To **set up an autoloading system** : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php (but it's more for classes, may not help you but it's important to know it exists)
- To use the **_*DIR*_ constant** (see Tivie reply) if you have one unique PHP file "entrance" (the "bootstrap file") which is called all the time (which should be the case!)

Also, when you say :

> for example i have this include in my postpage.php which is located at
>   example.com/c/postpage.php:

Be sure to understand fully the fact that the "path" URL (example.com/foo) and the path file on the disk can be totally different, and totally unlinked.

So, in your case, as you seems to have one directory for layout stuff (header/footer/...) and maybe one other for templates, the easiest thing is probably to add these 2 paths in your php.ini.

Then just call : `include('head.php')` and you're done.

You can also just add in your include_path the base directory of your project, and then call `include('includes/overall/head.php')`

Answer (score 0):

```
include "include/header.php";
include "include/head.php";
```

if you are select file from an other folder then coding will be like this

```
include "foldername/filename.php";
```